# Game Boy emulator with a full debugger?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, gameboy

As part of the work I've been doing to answer [this question about the technical workings of a glitch in Pokémon Red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876642/deconstructing-pokemon-glitches), I've been looking for a way to use a standard debugger to debug a Game Boy ROM.  Although many of the emulators I've found have some support for debugging, nothing I've found so far has been helpful.

As a background, as of now I have tried to use the Visual Boy Advance built-in features to do debugging, but they aren't particularly useful for what I'm trying to do.  VBA lacks the ability to set breakpoints, and since it steps forward at the level of frames rather than instructions I'm unable to see how the code is executing when I actually need it to.  Although VBA says that it supports GDB debugging, I have been completely unable to get it working.  I tried cross-compiling GDB for ARM as per the instructions, but could not get GDB to connect to the emulator (it would recognize that there was a program to connect to, but reported that the protocol had been violated).  I repeated this with similar success in both Windows with Cygwin and on Ubuntu Linux.  A friend and I tried to use Insight/GDB, but ran into exactly the same problems.

I also tried to use the NO$GBA debugger, but it refused to load my ROM for Pokémon Red (and then insulted me by saying that nothing I could try to do would fix it, as the file was just flat-out wrong).

Additionally, I tried downloading [this version](http://labmaster.bios.net.nz/vba-sdl-h/) of Visual Boy Advance that claims to have a debugger in it, but for some reason I can't get it to enable the debugger.  Pressing F11 as per its instructions has no effect whatsoever.

I believe that I've done my due diligence trying to get a debugger working, and I'm surprised that not a single one of them has worked.  Does anyone know of a simple, straightforward way to debug Game Boy games using standard debugging techniques?  I'm interested mostly in being able to put in memory write breakpoints (to see what routine is clobbering certain parts of memory).  I would really appreciate it if someone with first-hand experience doing this could provide details on how to do this, as online resources on the subject seem pretty limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the site [GbaDev.org](http://www.gbadev.org) and look on the forums.  This is the best spot on the web for GBA or even GBC questions.  I can tell you that there are many versions of VBA and no$ out and about.  The No$ you want was technically a pay for version, but Martin Korth hasn't been answering emails or anything for years now and I'm not sure of its status anymore.  I can also answer some questions for you personally if you'd like or help you with the debugger.

I was able to go to the no$ main website, download the windows version of **no$gmb**, and use it to debug when run in B/W mode - should be sufficient for you needs.  F12 opens roms, F2 toggles break points, space traces, F3 steps over, Ctrl-G takes you to an address (or symbol), and Ctrl_B allows conditional break points (by far the most powerful feature for you to use.)  For instance, (3000)! would set a read/write breakpoint on address 0x3000.  (0300..03003)! sets on a range.  As you are looking for specific address changes, this is what you want.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to debug your old gameboy games you can also use [bgb](http://bgb.bircd.org/) which has several debugging options such as tracing, breakpoints, profiler and a lot more.

Answer (score 5):

No$GBA is for GBA games; you want NO$GMB. Note that it's very buggy, and without a registered version (which may be impossible to get legitimately) rather crippled.

bgb is free and is very similar to No$GMB, but even buggier.

VBA is supposed to have a debugger, but there are a million different versions out there, so good luck finding the right one.

Comment: "but even buggier"? I haven't seen a single bug in bgb. What is it?

Answer (score 2):

[VBA-M](https://github.com/visualboyadvance-m/visualboyadvance-m) has a bunch of debugging tools under "Tools" menu, including memory & tile inspectors and a disassembler. It even has support for GDB. I didn't test with any frontends like [gdbgui](https://www.gdbgui.com/), or VSCode's GDB support, so YMMV, but the other built-in tools look pretty decent.

Go to the [releases section](https://github.com/visualboyadvance-m/visualboyadvance-m/releases) for a build for your platform (arch linux also has it in AUR, for easy install in package manager.)

Here it is running some of the tools on a Mac:
[image]

Comment: I also got BGB to run in wine on mac/arch-linux, but for the particular ROM I am working on, VBA-M was better because it has the memory-viewer (I needed to actually see what bytes were in the SRAM.)